# ¿Cómo hacer un replace en JavaScript de algo entre paréntesis, distinguiendo según el contenido del mismo?

Tags: javascript, regex

Llevo un rato investigando cómo hacer este *replace* en JavaScript, y lo mismo no se puede.

Parto de una cadena como

```
Base.direcciones(Email).direccionEmail.Otros(2).EstosOtros
```

y quiero

- Cambiar los puntos por `$p`
- Eliminar los paréntesis de cierre
- Cambiar los paréntesis  de apertura por `$g`, cuando entre paréntesis hay caracteres alfanuméricos (que siempre empezarán por letra)
- Cambiar los paréntesis  de apertura por `$l`, cuando entre paréntesis hay caracteres numéricos

En la expresión que he dado como ejemplo pueden aparecer sin ningún orden particular (tanto `direcciones(Email).Otros(2)` como `Otros(2).direcciones(Email)` ).

Llevo un rato jugando con variantes de

```
miCadena
    .replace(/\./g, "$p")
    .replace(/\(\d/g,"$l")
    .replace(/\(\w/g,"$g")
    .replace(/\)/g,"");
```

Pero el problema es que `/\(\d/g` y `/\(\w/g` me detectan si al paréntesis le sigue número o letra, pero me lo cambian también, por lo que termino con cosas como  `Base$pdirecciones$gmail$pdireccionEmail$pOtros$l$pEstosOtros` que no es el resultado deseado (porque me he comido la primera letra del *string* entre paréntesis y el primer numero entre paréntesis).

Cuál es la forma de hacer esos *replace* para que con `(Email)` me ponga `$gEmail` y con `(123)` me ponga `$l123` (es decir, hacer el *replace* manteniendo el contenido entre paréntesis)?

A estas alturas ya me he decido a usar una función en lugar de una expresión regular y *parsear* estos casos "a mano", pero quería publicar aquí a ver si algún gurú de JavaScript o de expresiones regulares me puede echar una mano sobre cómo distinguir los casos en el *replace* y sustituirlos manteniendo el contenido entre paréntesis.

---

Añado: He terminado con algo como esto, que todavía lo estoy haciendo a *prueba de balas*, pero me gustaría saber si hay una solución usando regex como en mi intento original.

```
var _getEntryHandleFromPropertyRef = function(propertyRef){
  var propertiesComponents = propertyRef.split(".");
  var entryHandle = propertiesComponents[0]
  for(var k = 1; k < propertiesComponents.length; k++){
    var component = propertiesComponents[k];
    var leftParenthesisPos = component.indexOf("(");
    var auxReplace = "";

    if(leftParenthesisPos > 0 ){
        auxReplace = ""
        //number or letter?
        if (isNaN(component[leftParenthesisPos+1])){//brittle: assumes closing parenthesis
            auxReplace = component.replace(/\(/g,"$g").replace(/\)/g,"");
        }else{
            auxReplace = component.replace(/\(/g,"$l").replace(/\)/g,"");
        }
        entryHandle +=  "$p"+ auxReplace
    }else{
        entryHandle +=  "$p"+ component
    }

  }
  return entryHandle;
}
```

Comment: En el título dice según el primer caracter, pero en la pregunta dice según el contenido del paréntesis... ¿qué debería comprobar? ¿sólo el primero o todo? ¿y qué pasa si entre paréntesis no es un alfanumérico?

Comment: Entre paréntesis voy a tener solo números o alfanumérico empezando por letra, así que con el primer carácter voy a saber seguro si  lo que hay entre paréntesis es un número puro o alfanumérico. Yo he hecho la distinción de casos con el primer carácter y posiblemente de ahí mi problema con la regex. Puedes usar lo que sea más cómodo para la solución. Si lo de dentro del paréntesis no es alfanumérico es un numero a la fuerza. Otras partes del código han validado que eso se cumpla en la cadena.

Comment: @Mariano Si crees que el título es más claro con "[...] algo entre paréntesis distinguiendo casos según en el contenido" editamos el título para clarificarlo.

Comment: Da igual... Con tu comentario me quedó claro y estoy escribiendo la respuesta (según el primer caracter hace que la expresión sea apenas más sencilla).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separemos los conceptos:

**1. Usar el texto que coincidió en el reemplazo**. Cuando en regex se utilizan paréntesis se crea un grupo, y ese grupo guarda una referencia al texto con el que se coincidió ([referencia en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Usando_par%C3%A9ntesis)). Al reemplazar, podemos utilizar ese mismo texto. `$1` guarda la referencia al primero grupo, `$2` al segundo y así sucesivamente.

Para eliminar los paréntesis, debemos hacer que coincida con todo, y reemplazarlos por el contenido. Este regex puede parecer confuso:

```
/\(([^)]*)\)/g
```

pero es sencillo si analizamos:

- `\(` - coincide con un `"("` literal en el texto.
- `([^)]*)` - es el primer grupo, que coincide con:

  - `[^)]*` - cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean un `")"`.
- `\)` - coincide con un `")"` literal en el texto.
- `/g` - modificador para que se reemplacen todas las coincidencias, no solo la primera.

Demo:

```js
//Ejemplo para cambiar paréntesis por corchetes
var texto  = "(abc) (123) (def)",
    regex  = /\(([^)]*)\)/g,
    reempl = "[$1]";

console.log(texto.replace(regex, reempl));
```

De esta forma, podríamos utilizar 2 expresiones para lograr lo que estás buscando:

```js
resultado = texto.replace(/\((\d+)\)/g, "$l$1")
                 .replace(/\((\w+)\)/g, "$g$1");
```

**2. Usar una función callback para reemplazar según con qué coincidió**. Una forma más avanzada, sería hacer coincidir con todo el contenido del paréntesis, y reemplazar según si el primer caracter es un dígito o no. Para eso, podemos utilizar un grupo opcional:

```
/\((\d)?(\[^)]*)\)/g
```

- `\(` - coincide con un `"("` literal en el texto.
- `(\d)?` - es el primer grupo, que es opcional (por el `?` al final) y coincide con:

  - `\d` - un dígito.
- `([^)]*)` - es el segundo grupo, que coincide con:

  - `[^)]*` - cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean un `")"`.
- `\)` - coincide con un `")"` literal en el texto.
- `/g` - modificador para que se reemplacen todas las coincidencias, no solo la primera.

Ahora bien, ¿Cómo reemplazamos por cosas diferentes según si se guardó una referencia al texto que coincidió con `(\d)` (el primer grupo)? La función [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) acepta un segundo parámetro como una función,

```
cadena.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[,   flags]);
```

que es ejecutada al evaluar cada reemplazo. El texto referenciado de cada grupo es pasado como parámetro a esa función. Así, podemos llamar a:

```
texto.replace( regex, function( coincidenciaGlobal, grupo1, grupo2) {
    // código que tiene que devolver el texto por el que se está reemplazando...
});
```

y evaluar el contenido de `grupo1` para ver por qué reemplazarlo.

En el caso en que el grupo `(\d)?` no sea utilizado en la coincidencia, el parámetro `grupo1` que se pasa a la función no contendrá ningún valor.

---

**Código**

```js
var regex  = /\((\d)?([^)]*)\)/g,
    reempl = {
        punto: "$p",
        nums:  "$l",
        alnum: "$g"
    },
    
    texto  = "Base.direcciones(Email).direccionEmail.Otros(2).EstosOtros";
    
//Reemplazar puntos por $p
texto = texto.replace(/\./g, reempl.punto);

//Reemplazar paréntesis
texto = texto.replace(regex, function (match, grupo1, grupo2) {
    if (grupo1) { //empieza por número (porque el primer grupo coincidió)
        //reemplazar por $l seguido del contenido de ambos grupos
        return reempl.nums + grupo1 + grupo2;
        
    } else {      //no empieza por número
        //reemplazar por $g seguido del contenido del segundo grupo
        return reempl.alnum + grupo2;
    }
});

console.log("Resultado:", texto);
```

**Resultado**

```
Base$pdirecciones$gEmail$pdireccionEmail$pOtros$l2$pEstosOtros
```

---

**3. Según el contenido (no sólo el primer caracter)**. Usando esta misma estrategia, podemos diferenciar según el contenido completo de los paréntesis con:

```
/\(((\d+)|[^)]*)\)/g
```

donde el grupo 2 sólo va a guardar una referencia si el contenido es un entero.

```js
var texto = "Base.direcciones(Email).direccionEmail.Otros(2).EstosOtros",
    regex = /\(((\d+)|[^)]*)\)/g,
    resultado;

resultado = texto.replace( regex, function(match,g1,g2){
    return (g2 ? "$l" : "$g") + g1;
});

console.log(resultado);
    // => Base.direcciones$gEmail.direccionEmail.Otros$l2.EstosOtros
```

**4. Incluir todas las condiciones dentro de la misma expresión**. De yapa, si el texto siempre contiene puntos seguidos de `\w+`, y opcionalmente con paréntesis, podríamos poner todo dentro de la misma expresión, para reemplazar tanto los puntos como los paréntesis con:

```
/\.(\w+)(\(((\d)|[^)]*)\))?/g
```

```js
var texto = "Base.direcciones(Email).direccionEmail.Otros(2).EstosOtros",
    regex = /\.(\w+)(\(((\d)|[^)]*)\))?/g,
    resultado;

resultado = texto.replace( regex, function(match,g1,g2,g3,g4){
    if (g2) {  //tiene paréntesis?
        if (g4) {  //es un entero?
            return "$p" + g1 + "$l" + g3;
        } else {
            return "$p" + g1 + "$g" + g3;
        }
    } else {
        return "$p" + g1;
    }
});

console.log(resultado);
    // => Base$pdirecciones$gEmail$pdireccionEmail$pOtros$l2$pEstosOtros
```